# How is convolving Haar measure with itself over subsets enough to define subgroups?

Tags: probability, group-theory, haar-measure

In [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/40382/69208), Terry Tao says that Gaussians are "a subgroup of $\Bbb R$".

> When you convolve Haar probability measure on a (compact) subgroup with itself, you get back the same measure, and this can in fact be used as a definition of such subgroups. If you convolve a Gaussian probability measure with itself, you almost get back the same Gaussian measure, but it has spread out by a factor of $\sqrt 2$. So Gaussians are in some sense a "$\sqrt 2$-approximate group".

I don't understand this comment, or how it means that Gaussians can be viewed as a subgroup of $\Bbb R$.

How can you define subgroups through this? Perhaps this?

> A subset, $H$ of a group $G$ with Haar measure $\mu$ is called a *subgroup* if $\mu |_H=\mu\ast\mu|_H$.

How does this show that a Gaussian is a subgroup of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: I think Tao is just trying to make an analogy. I do not think it is meant to be taken literally.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I don't even understand the analogy, lol

Comment: Could the analogy be that Gaussians are idempotent except for the $\sqrt{2}$ factor, and in general idempotent probability measures have compact subgroups as support? So a Gaussian "approximately" corresponds to a subgroup? (What that subgroup should be in the case of the Gaussian, I wouldn't know.)

Comment: @Bart One thing is that Gaussians aren't Haar measure, right? Where does the Haar part come in?

Comment: The Haar part would be that an idempotent probability measure is a Haar measure on the subgroup that is its support. By approximately being idempotent the Gaussian is approximately a Haar measure on its support (whatever that should be).

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, I am not Terry Tao and this answer has some speculation on my part. The interesting bit of theory is that subgroups (of a compact group) can be identified by algebraic properties in the semigroup of probability measure. This post only aims to answer the question, "How can you define a subgroup through this?".

Let $G$ be a compact group and $\mathcal{P}(G)$ be the collection of regular Borel probability measures on $G$. This is a semigroup under the convolution operation. There is a classical theorem of Wendel which connects idempotent elements in the semigroup $\mathcal{P}(G)$ (i.e. measures such that $\mu * \mu = \mu$) with compact subgroups of $G$. In particular, each idempotent measure is actually the Haar measure of a closed subgroup. So, from an idempotent measure, taking the support gives a compact subgroup, and from a compact subgroup, taking the Haar measure results in an idempotent measure.

So, we can say that a subset $A \subset G$ is a (compact) subgroup if there exists an idempotent measure $\mu \in \mathcal{P}(G)$ such that $\sup(\mu) = A$.

Rudin extended this theorem to the locally compact abelian case. In particular, any idempotent probability measure here concentrates on a compact subgroup.